# Full fitting background image without expanding

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Rhq/1/). I want to get full fit the background image withouth streching. Because when i resize window image will be distorted. If i change the css with

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8100/8601158004_173413335e_k.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

image doesn't strech anymore but then image will be enormously big. How can set the background image properly?
I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `background-size`-property **`cover`** for this:

```
#homee {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8100/8601158004_173413335e_k.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2Rhq/4/

**Update**

If you've to support oldIE try my super-simple jquery plugin for this:

https://github.com/yckart/jquery.fitpic.js

Comment: You should add `background-position: 50% 50%;` to center the background.